# AngularFire2 AuthCredentials

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm struggling with getting the authCredentials in AngularFire2 to reauthenticate the user for sensitive methods, such as delete, password update, email update, etc. and I get this error:

> Property 'AuthCredential' does not exist on type 'typeof auth'.

Here is the code for it:

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }
    reauthenticated() {
        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
        const credential = firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
        user.auth.reauthenticate(credential)
            .then(() => { })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I just found that you need to get the credentials manually and this is the only way. You need to ask the user to type his email and password, or just the password and you get the email from subscribing to AngularFire, in order to execute this method, then you use his user details.

```
const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
user.auth.reauthenticate(credential);
```

Comment: There is no EmailAuthProvider in the AngularFire2 sdk how does this work?

Answer (score -1):

We were running into a problem where we needed to use EmailAuthProvider.credential(user, pass) but when we tried using the official firebase package as a work around it would freeze up our Ionic production build. The angularfire2 package however wouldn't freeze up our build. This is a known issue that Ionic has with the firebase package that hasn't been fixed yet.

To work around this we ended up creating a fork of angularfire2 that has a emailAuthProviderCredential function on the AngularFireAuth object. It's literally just a pass through that exposes firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user, pass).

Here's the fork: https://github.com/seed2spoon/angularfire2

So, if you absolutely need to create credentials in angularfire2 without installing the firebase package feel free to use this fork via "npm install
https://github.com/seed2spoon/angularfire2/releases/download/5.1.1-s2s/5.1.1-s2s.tar.gz"